# Replacing each letter with its number self

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to take each letter of a word (a is 1, b is 2, etc.), then add them all together to find the sum of all the numbers. For example, “apple” would be 50. I have this code:

```
conversions = {
'a': 1,
'b': 2,
'c': 3,
'd': 4,
'e': 5,
'f': 6,
'g': 7,
'h': 8,
'i': 9,
'j': 10,
'k': 11,
'l': 12,
'm': 13,
'n': 14,
'o': 15,
'p': 16,
'q': 17,
'r': 18,
's': 19,
't': 20,
'u': 21,
'v': 22,
'w': 23,
'x': 24,
'y': 25,
'z': 26
}

def conversion(word):
    for letter in word:
        word.replace(letter, str(conversions[letter]))
    word = list(word)
    for number in word:
        number = int(number)
    return sum(word)
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

I’ve probably done some dumb mistake, but I can’t seem to figure out what the problem is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `for number in word: number = int(number)` does not change the characters to numbers in the original word.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable. `word.replace()` returns the modifies string, it doesn't update `word`. And you can't change a string into a list of numbers anyway.

You don't need to use `replace` at all, just add up the conversions.

```
def conversion(word):
    return sum(conversions[letter] for letter in word)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are definitely making things unnecessarily complicated. All lowercase alphabetic characters are sequentially coded. Get their codes and add them up:

```
def conversion(word):
    return sum(ord(x) - ord('a') + 1 for x in word)

conversion('apple')
#50
```

Beware that this code will *not* handle upper-case letters or punctuation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (this will handle upper and lowercase):

```
def conversion(word):
   return sum([ord(x.lower()) - 96 for x in word])
```

```
>>> conversion("AppLe")
50
```